# Is there a method to map clusters created for two independent data sets with certain common parameters?

Tags: r, clustering

Was thinking of a problem, but not yet clear on the exact statement.Please excuse the vagueness. The general idea I have might be explained using the following example:

The two sets of data are students and teachers. We can cluster the students data to define 5 different classes based on marks, nationality,language, areas of interest etc. And cluster teachers into 5 different classes based on parameters like experience, area of expertise, language etc.

Now, can we match the student and teacher cluster to get the best mapping? Or should it be done at an individual level. i.e each teacher to student mapping?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Particularly, what you mean by "mapping" in your case. And how the mapping can occur between datasets qith seemingly different attributes (you clustered teachers by one attributes and students by different attributes).

Comment: Also, how do you measure "best match"? I don't see why clustering should be better here than simply assigning by best match individually.

Answer (score 1):

SanilB's terminology isn't precise, but the drift of the question seems clear enough for anyone with a background in educational data analysis, I think.

By "mapping," are you referring to recovering the hierarchical relationships that exist within classrooms and schools between students and teachers? Or are you referring to identifying and somehow optimizing an assignment of students to teacher "types" in order to maximize student performance?

The former assumes a structure with a single student-teacher relationship, the kind of organization typically seen in US elementary schools. Otherwise and as is true for most middle and high schools where a single student will have multiple teachers across multiple subjects, it becomes much more difficult to disentangle separate and distinct influences. These are the kinds of challenges that *VAT* or value-added teaching models attempt to decompose.

The latter objective of maximizing student performance is a much, much more difficult, almost impossible challenge. One unarticulated implication of it is the assumption of a kind of experimental design (random assignment of students and teachers based on their "profiles") that is almost impossible to enforce beyond small pilot studies. Not to mention that the cluster profiles are, at best, only weakly predictive.